# Curve modifier stretch mesh

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

Is it possible to avoid this stretching of stitches when deforming with curve modifier?

[image]

Comment: I think it is not possible. You should consider using a another curve for the lace, OR make so the curve is along the lace instead of being at the center.

Comment: I tried it but it does not work. Even tried with duplication along curve and it is stretching it again. I decided to do that in Houdini, get what I wanted in 2 min http://screencloud.net/v/akCT1. Will have to switch entire project to it as I need to animate it.

Comment: I does work... be sure to tune the object's origin appropriately to its geometry (sorry but I won't have time to write an answer now, maybe someone else will do)

Comment: I understand what are you talking about but still there are some stretching and I can not have them. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

*Applying transformations* and proper placement of the *origin points*'ll do the job here.
[image]

*Apply the transformations* for all the objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and set all the objects' *origin points* in the same place as pictured below. 
[image]

You may then change the position of the belt.
[image]